# Get value between brackets inside single cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have below values in a cell :

say A5 - ( example are 3 values, it can be 'n' values )

```
         Hello Im (User1)
         Hello Im (User2)
         Hello Im (User3)
```

I want to get values inside brackets i.e. User1,User2,User3 in a seperate sheet for further manupulation.

I tried multiple ways but it all works if it has a single value and not multiple values

Below methods i tried

```
cellValue = "Hello Im (User1)"
OP = instr(cellValue, "(")
CP = instr(cellValue, ")")
EV = mid(cellValue, OP+1, CP-OP-1)
```

I even tried converting text to column but didnt work.

Comment: Your code should have worked.  Why do you think you have a problem.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Split

```
Sub SplitTest()
    Dim e, ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, s As String, r As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input")
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output")
    s = ws.Range("A5").Value
    For Each e In Split(s, vbLf)
        r = r + 1
        sh.Cells(r, 1).Value = Split(Split(e, "(")(1), ")")(0)
    Next e
End Sub
```

Comment: Great! worked ! Thanks. I was not aware of Split functionality.

Comment: How can I have this in a seperate sheet instead in a immediate window?